# ssis - Cannot Create Integration Services Project

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm newbe to SSIS.
I can't create a SSIS project.When I open SSDT and create Integration Services Project ,It just immediately say `"creating project 'ProjectName' ... project creation failed."`
I'm using sql server 2012 and vs 2012 .
Thnaks.

Comment: Please refer to some forums related to SSIS which will walk you through the creation of Integration Services Project.